# Sorting products in order ASC and DSC

Tags: javascript, html, sorting

**Hi!** I've been working on my website and i wanna make sorting by ASC and DSC in my products, im new at javascript and i don't understand a lot of the point, the script is copied from a guy who was asking for it too, but it didn't work out for me.
Here is my **Script** and **html**

```js
var ascending = false;

$('.tab-content').on('click', '.sortByPrice', function() {

  var sorted = $('.product').sort(function(a, b) {
    return (ascending ==
      (convertToNumber($(a).find('.price').html()) <
        convertToNumber($(b).find('.price').html()))) ? 1 : -1;
  });

  if (ascending) {
    ascending = false;
    $(".sortByPrice").html("Sort by Price: descending");
  } else {
    ascending = true;
    $(".sortByPrice").html("Sort by Price: ascending");
  }


  $('.results').html(sorted);
});

var convertToNumber = function(value) {
  return parseFloat(value.replace('$', ''));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- WWI Minifigs -->
<div class="small-container">
  <h2 class="title" id="customminifigures">WWI Minifigs</h2>
  <a class="sortByPrice">Sort By Price</a>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4">
      <a href="Edith Cavell.html"><img src="Products img/Edith Cavell/Edith Cavell.png"></a>
      <h4>Edith Cavell
      </h4>
      <p>$31.00
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      <a href="WWI US Infantry.html" target="_blank"><img src="Products img/WWI US Infantry/WWI US Infantry.png"></a>
      <h4>WWI US Infantry
      </h4>
      <p>$26.00</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      <a href="WWI Ottoman Infantry.html"><img src="Products img/WWI Ottoman Infantry/WWI Ottoman Infantry.png"></a>
      <h4>WWI Ottoman Infantry</h4>
      <p>$29.00</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If two prices are the same, your sort comparison function will return the wrong answer. When two keys are identical, the sort function should return 0. (Actually, it's basically "double wrong". Comparing to the "ascending" flag like that is also incorrect.

Comment: Alright, sorry for wasting your time im not the right person to do this stuff, thank you for your answers.

Comment: So I did answer your original question

Answer (score 0):

Please study this

I added classes to the container and to the tabs, added jQuery and bootstrap too

```js
let ascending = true;
const convertToNumber = value => parseFloat(value.replace('$', ''));

$('.small-container').on('click', '.sortByPrice', function() {

  var sorted = $('.product').sort(function(a, b) {
    const priceA = convertToNumber($(a).find('.price').html())
    const priceB = convertToNumber($(b).find('.price').html())
    return ascending ? priceA - priceB : priceB - priceA
  });
    
  $(this).html(`Sort by Price: ${ascending ? "descending" : "ascending"}`);
  ascending = !ascending;


  $('.products').html(sorted);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<!-- WWI Minifigs -->
<div class="small-container">
  <h2 class="title" id="customminifigures">WWI Minifigs</h2>
  <a class="sortByPrice">Sort By Price</a>
  <div class="row products">
    <div class="col-4 product">
      <a href="Edith Cavell.html"><img src="Products img/Edith Cavell/Edith Cavell.png"></a>
      <h4>Edith Cavell
      </h4>
      <p class="price">$31.00
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 product">
      <a href="WWI US Infantry.html" target="_blank"><img src="Products img/WWI US Infantry/WWI US Infantry.png"></a>
      <h4>WWI US Infantry
      </h4>
      <p class="price">$26.00</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 product">
      <a href="WWI Ottoman Infantry.html"><img src="Products img/WWI Ottoman Infantry/WWI Ottoman Infantry.png"></a>
      <h4>WWI Ottoman Infantry</h4>
      <p class="price">$29.00</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#patientTable thead th').click(function(){
        //Add parameter for remembering order type
        $(this).attr('data-order', ($(this).attr('data-order') === 'desc' ? 'asc':'desc'));
       //Add aditional parameters to keep track column that was clicked
       sorttable(this, $('#patientTable thead th').index(this));
    });
});
function sorttable(header, index){
 var $tbody = $('table tbody');
 var order = $(header).attr('data-order');
 $tbody.find('tr').sort(function (a, b) {
 var tda = $(a).find('td:eq(' + index + ')').text();
 var tdb = $(b).find('td:eq(' + index + ')').text();
     //Order according to order type
     return (order === 'asc' ? (tda > tdb ? 1 : tda < tdb ? -1 : 0) : (tda < tdb ? 1 : tda > tdb ? -1 : 0));
}).appendTo($tbody);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please use the *Post answer* button only for actual answers. This code is not relevant to OP's HTML in any way. Random sorting code will not help people who are new to scripting